# What's the best way to separate numbers manually for learning algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, function, class, oop

I am learning Java and wonder how I can get two numbers in same line.

Is this algorithm is okay, what can I do improve? What can you suggest me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static int Separate(String Values, int Order){
        String toReturn = "";
        int Counter = 0;

        for(int Iterator = 0; Iterator < Values.length(); Iterator = Iterator + 1){
            if(Values.charAt(Iterator) == ' ') {
                if(Order == Counter) break;
                else{
                    toReturn = "";
                    Counter = Counter + 1;
                }
            }
            else toReturn += Values.charAt(Iterator);
            
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(toReturn);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner Entry = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter two numbers separated by space: ");
        String Number = Entry.nextLine();

        int Frst = Separate(Number, 0);
        int Scnd = Separate(Number, 1);

        
    }
}
```

Comment: So the code already works? I think [codereview.se] is better (read their help center before asking)

Comment: Yes, it's working.

Comment: Your code might not behave like intended if more than one space is between the numbers. I would recommend to use `Values.split("\\s+")` to split the String where at least one space is.

Comment: Remark: In java it is a widely used convention mo make variable names start with a lower case character.

Comment: You're right @MrSmith42. Not working with one more space. I will try to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what can I do improve? What can you suggest me?

Adopt the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html):

1. Method Names are `camelCase`, starting with a lower case letter
2. Field and Property Names and Method Argument Names are `camelCase`, too

Basically only Class and Interface Names start with an upper case letter in Java.

```java
public static int separate(String values, int order){
  String toReturn = "";
  int counter = 0;

  for(int iterator = 0; ...) { ...
```

Else I'd say: This algorithm is pretty solid for a beginner. It's easy to understand what's going on.

Of course Java provides much more sophisticated tools to solve this, using for example Regular Expressions with `myString.split(...)`, or Streams with `IntStream intStream = myString.chars()`.

Last but not least you could add Exception Handling: What happens if `Integer.parseInt` is given some non-number? It will crash.

```
try {
  return Integer.parseInt(toReturn);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // when "toReturn" cannot be parsed to an int, return a
  // default value instead of crashing your application
  return 0;
}
```

Or if crashing is the desired behavior, or you can ensure that this method is never called with an illegal String, leave it as it is (= don't add `try catch`)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you've done is great for well-formatted input, where you have a single space character between the numbers. As others have pointer out, following Java naming conventions will greatly improve the readability of your code.

Handling sequences of space characters, possible before, between, and after your numbers is a little tricky. The general pattern would be to consume any sequences of spaces, remember the current position, consume the sequence of digits, then if we're at the correct position return the parsed number.

```
public static int separate(String str, int order) 
{
    for(int i = 0, pos = 0; ; pos++)
    {
        while(i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == ' ') i += 1;
  
        int j = i;
        while(i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) != ' ') i += 1;
       
        if(i == j) throw new IllegalStateException("Missing number!");
        
        if(order == pos) 
        {
            // handle NumberFormatException
            return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(j, i));       
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
String s = "  23432   798  44";
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    System.out.print(separate(s, i) + " ");
```

Output:

```
23432 798 44
```